# Proving the Leibniz Integral Rule

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, leibniz-integral-rule

I've been wondering if there is a fairly simple proof or derivation for the following (called the Leibniz Rule):

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(x,t)dx = \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{t}}dx+ f(b(t),t)\frac{d}{dt}b(t)-f(a(t),t)\frac{d}{dt}a(t)$$

What I tried doing is integrating by parts the leftmost integral, and then applying the time derivative to what it's equal to. However, it seems the other side is very far from what the result above. A small hint would suffice as I like trying to prove things on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: first try to see what is $\partial _y\int_{a}^y f(x,t)\mathop{}\!d x$ and $\partial _t \int_{a}^y f(x,t)\mathop{}\!d x$, the first case follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus, the latter from the continuity of $\partial_t f$ and the definition of partial derivative.

Then for $F(y,t):=\int_{a}^y f(x,t)\mathop{}\!d x$ you will get an expression for $\nabla F(y,t)$, then setting $\varphi (t):=(g(t),t)$ for some differentiable $g$ you can compute $(F\circ \varphi )'(t)$ using the chain rule.

Finally the general case follows from the decomposition
$$
\int_{h(t)}^{g(t)}f(x,t)\mathop{}\!d x=\int_{a}^{g(t)}f(x,t)\mathop{}\!d x-\int_{a}^{h(t)}f(x,t)\mathop{}\!d x
$$

---

We will show that $\partial _t \int_{a}^{y}f(x,t)\mathop{}\!d x=\int_{a}^y \partial _t f(x,t)\mathop{}\!d x$ when $\partial _t f$ is continuous. Note that, as the partial derivative in $t$ of $f$ is continuous then for fixed $t_0$ the function defined by

$$
q_{t_0}(x,h):=\begin{cases}
\frac{f(x,t_0+h)-f(x,t_0)}{h},&h\neq 0\\
\partial _t f(x,t_0),& h=0
\end{cases}
$$

is continuous, therefore it is uniformly continuous in the compact set $[a,y]\times [-r ,r ]$ for any chosen $r >0$, so for every $\epsilon >0$ there is some $\delta \in(0,r)$ such that $|q_{t_0}(x,h)-\partial _t f(x,t_0)|<\epsilon $ for all $(x,h)\in[a,y]\times (-\delta ,\delta )$, therefore

$$
\left|\int_{a}^y (q_{t_0}(x,h)-\partial _t f(x,t_0))\mathop{}\!d x\right|\leqslant \int_{a}^y |q_{t_0}(x,h)-\partial _t f(x,t_0)|\mathop{}\!d x<(y-a)\epsilon 
$$

what shows that

$$
\partial _t \int_{a}^y f(x,t_0)\mathop{}\!d x=\lim_{h\to 0}\int_{a}^y q_{t_0}(x,h)\mathop{}\!d x=\int_{a}^y \partial _t f(x,t_0)\mathop{}\!d x
$$

Comment: Since I'm not that experienced with math, what does this symbol $:=$ mean? Also, I found $\partial_{t}\int_{a}^{y} f(x,t) dx$ without using "local uniform continuity", or at least without being aware that I've used it; could you please explain why that is needed?

Comment: the symbol $:=$ means that the LHS is defined to represent the RHS, in short, it means "defined by". You need uniform continuity to show that the limit of the integral is the integral of the limit, that is, to exchange limit and integral in the definition of derivative as $f(x,t)$ take values of $x$ in an interval (the interval $[a,y]$). By local uniform continuity I mean that $f$ is uniformly continuous in $[a,y]\times [t-h,t+h]$ for some $h>0$

Comment: Could you please explain why the limit of the integral being equal to the integral of the limit requires this condition? Or, if it is a long explanation, could you advise me as to where I can find a source that explains it (preferably suitable for an undergrad sophomore)?

Comment: I added a detailed explanation in the body of the question

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'm suprised the proof doesn't use the definition of integrals

Comment: @Omar we used some properties of the integral (of Riemann) in this proof, by example that $|\int_a ^b f(x) dx|\leqslant \int_a^b |f(x)|dx$, what can be deduced from it definition. Also we used the property that if $|f(x)|\leqslant c$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ then $\int_a^b |f(x)|dx\leqslant \int_a^b cdx=c(b-a)$, this can be deduced again from the definition of the integral (this property is named as positivity of the integral)

Comment: Perfect, thanks again!